# Highcharts: Graph not visible on ipad

Tags: ipad, highcharts

The following chart displays fine in Safari and Chrome on the desktop; however, it will not show in either browser on the iPad (iOS 9, iPad Air 2).  Only the background shows.  Is there a setting for allowing the chart to show on mobile devices?

http://jsfiddle.net/quint/d7gr6r1g/6/

```js
//-------------------------------------------------------
Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.symbols.line = function(x, y, width, height) {
    return ['M',x ,y + width / 2,'L',x+height,y + width / 2];
};
//-------------------------------------------------------
Highcharts.setOptions({
    chart:{
        type:'bar',
        margin:[5,15,10,100],
        backgroundColor: '#383838',
    },
    credits:{enabled:false},
    exporting:{enabled:false},
    legend:{enabled:false},
    title:{text:''},
    xAxis:{
        tickLength:0,
        lineColor:'#ffffff',
        lineWidth:1,
        labels:{style:{fontWeight:'bold', color: '#ffffff'}},       
    },
    yAxis:{
        min:0,
        minPadding:0,
        maxPadding:0,
        tickColor:'#ffffff',
        tickWidth:1,
        tickLength:3,
        gridLineWidth:0,
        endOnTick:true,
        title:{text: ''},
        labels:{
            y:10,
            style:{
              color: '#ffffff',
                fontSize:'8px'
            },
            formatter:function(){
                if (this.isLast){
                    return this.value + ' %';
                }
                else{
                    return this.value;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip:{
        enabled:true,
        backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, .85)',
        borderWidth:0,
        shadow:true,
        style:{fontSize:'10px',padding:2},
        formatter:function() {
           return this.series.name + ": <strong>" + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,2) + "</strong>";
        }
    },
    plotOptions:{
        bar:{
            color:'rgba(102,112,86,1)',
            shadow:false,
            borderWidth:0,
        },
        scatter:{
            marker:{
                symbol:'line',
                lineWidth:3,
                radius:8,
                lineColor:'rgba(195, 84, 19, 1)'
            }
        }
    }
});

//-------------------------------------------------------
var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart:{renderTo:'container1'},
    xAxis:{
      categories:['ROUND 1'], },
    yAxis:{
        max:100,
        labels:{y:10,style:{fontSize:'8px', color: '#ffffff'}},    
        plotBands:[{from:0,to:100,color: 'rgba(209,219,183,1)'}]
    },
    series:[{name:'Measure',pointWidth:10,data:[80]},
            {name:'Target',type: 'scatter',data:[90]},
            {name:'Performance', type:'scatter',
              dataLabels: {
                    style:{
                    color: '#ffffff',
                    fontSize:'10px',
                },
                enabled: true,
                useHTML: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<div><img style="float: left; padding-right: 5px; min-width: 24px; max-width: 24px;" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"></div></div><div class="performance"style="text-align:center; font-size: 12px;"><div>' + this.point.value + '</div>';
                }
            },        
        data:[{x:0, value: '10%'}]
    }]
});



//-------------------------------------------------------
var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart:{renderTo:'container2'},
    xAxis:{categories:['ROUND 2']},
    yAxis:{
        max:100,
        labels:{y:10,style:{fontSize:'8px', color: '#ffffff'}},    
        plotBands:[{from:0,to:100,color: 'rgba(209,219,183,1)'}]
    },
    series:[{name:'Measure',pointWidth:10,data:[92]},
            {name:'Target',type: 'scatter',data:[95]},
            {name:'Performance', type:'scatter',
              dataLabels: {
                    style:{
                    color: '#ffffff',
                    fontSize:'10px',
                },
                enabled: true,
                useHTML: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<div><img style="float: left; padding-right: 5px; min-width: 24px; max-width: 24px;" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"></div></div><div class="performance"style="text-align:center; font-size: 12px;"><div>' + this.point.value + '</div>';
                }
            },        
        data:[{x:0, value: '5%'}]
    }]
});

//-------------------------------------------------------
var chart3 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart:{renderTo:'container3'},
    xAxis:{categories:['ROUND 3']},
    yAxis:{
        max:100,
        labels:{y:10,style:{fontSize:'8px', color: '#ffffff'}},    
        plotBands:[{from:0,to:100,color: 'rgba(209,219,183,1)'}]
    },
    series:[{name:'Measure',pointWidth:10,data:[75]},
            {name:'Target',type: 'scatter',data:[75]},
            {name:'Performance', type:'scatter',
              dataLabels: {
                    style:{
                    color: '#ffffff',
                    fontSize:'10px',
                },
                enabled: true,
                useHTML: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<div><img style="float: left; padding-right: 5px; min-width: 24px; max-width: 24px;" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"></div></div><div class="performance"style="text-align:center; font-size: 12px;"><div>' + this.point.value + '</div>';
                }
            },        
        data:[{x:0, value: ''}]
    }]
});

//-------------------------------------------------------
var chart4 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart:{renderTo:'container4'},
    xAxis:{categories:['ROUND 4']},
    yAxis:{
        max:1000,
        labels:{y:10,style:{fontSize:'8px', color: '#ffffff'}},    
        plotBands:[{from:0,to:1000,color: 'rgba(209,219,183,1)'}]
    },
    series:[{name:'Measure',pointWidth:10,data:[970]},
            {name:'Target',type: 'scatter',data:[850]},
            {name:'Performance', type:'scatter',
              dataLabels: {
                    style:{
                    color: '#ffffff',
                    fontSize:'10px',
                },
                enabled: true,
                useHTML: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<div><img style="float: left; padding-right: 5px; min-width: 24px; max-width: 24px;" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"></div></div><div class="performance"style="text-align:center; font-size: 12px;"><div>' + this.point.value + '</div>';
                }
            },        
        data:[{x:0, value: '10%'}]
    }]
});

//-------------------------------------------------------
var chart5 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart:{renderTo:'container5'},
    xAxis:{categories:['ROUND 5']},
    yAxis:{
        max:500,tickInterval:100,
        labels:{y:10,style:{fontSize:'8px', color: '#ffffff'}},    
        plotBands:[{from:0,to:500,color: 'rgba(209,219,183,1)'}]
    },
    series:[{name:'Measure',pointWidth:10,data:[475]},
            {name:'Target',type: 'scatter',data:[450]},
            {name:'Performance', type:'scatter',
              dataLabels: {
                    style:{
                    color: '#ffffff',
                    fontSize:'10px',
                },
                enabled: true,
                useHTML: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<div><img style="float: left; padding-right: 5px; min-width: 24px; max-width: 24px;" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"></div></div><div class="performance"style="text-align:center; font-size: 12px;"><div>' + this.point.value + '</div>';
                }
            },        
        data:[{x:0, value: '5%'}]
    }]
});
//-------------------------------------------------------


$('.performance').parent().parent().css({'top': 0, 'margin-left': 245, 'margin-top': 0});
```

Comment: Let me know which version of iOS do you use, because I run your example without any problems (iOS 9.1)

Comment: Thanks, Sebastian.  I copied over all of the code into a new fiddle, and now it works.  Strange.  The iOS version is the very latest.